# Can I use glossay.csv variables in Typescript

Tags: typescript, csv

I have to use a glossary.csv entry in my typescript file.

e.g. the entry is

```
customer.order,Order,en_US
customer.order,Bestellung,de_DE
```

I´m familiar with the use of csv in twig.files

```
{{ customer.order | trans }}
```

but not with ts.files. Is it even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are reading the csv data into your ts file.  You might want to make use of a package like Papaparse.

Comment: I could avoid the issue and placed the csv text in the twig and selected it via typescript